# Ribbons in Java, and Custom Buttons

Tags: java, windows, ribbon, office-2007

Is there some component or something that could help me create a ribbon that looks like the one in Office 2007. And Also is there a way to draw custom Close minimize maximize buttons?

Comment: Do you means this stupid new menu-bar layout? I always get confused by it ...

Comment: Also, are you using SWT, AWT, Swing, or something else for your GUI, or are you still free to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [SWT Ribbon](http://hexapixel.com/projects/ribbon). Looks like it should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using swing, check out the [Flamingo component suite](http://java.net/projects/flamingo/).